# 404 when browsing single document in Solritas

Tags: solr, solritas

I've set up an instance of Solr 4.2 based on the example directory provided with the distribution. When searching using the Solritas UI ( http://my.com:8983/solr/collection1/browse ) the search results page works fine. When I try to click on the id of one of the documents ( where the URL for the record with id "1234" is http://my.com:8983/solr/collection1/1234 ), I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file "richtext_doc.vm" under your /example/solr/collection1/conf/velocity.

Look for comment '## Title, hyperlinked' in this file. Just below is the place where hyperlinked-Title is shown & you can add the link to your document.  In my case, this is what I added:

```
 <a href="browse?q=id:${url}" target="_blank">
```

You can easily remove `target="_blank"` if you do not want document to open in a new page.

Hope it works for you!